# How to remove many core data objects at once?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm writing an iOS app and I'm using Core Data to store a series of `Event` objects (think birthdays, or christmas or meeting...etc).  Each `Event` object has a date attribute associated with it of type `NSDate`.

Throughout the course of my program I gather an NSArray of NSDate objects and I was wondering how do I delete the core data objects associated with these dates?  For example, if I have an array consisting of the dates 11/7 and 12/9 how do I delete any Event objects that have a date attribute of 11/7 or 12/9?

One possibility that I've thought of is to fetch all of the corresponding `Event` objects using predicates and fetch requests and then turn around and delete them all; however, this seems kinda inefficient.  What if one of my `Event` objects is really, really large...then won't it take forever to fetch it, just so that I can turn around and delete it?

I'm just wondering if there is a more elegant way to handle this...Thanks

Comment: It won't be slow to fetch them. Core data can return the objects as faults, which means none of their properties are fetched, just their ids. Fetching and deleting is the correct solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this with a single fetch - use the `IN` operator to construct a predicate using your NSArray of dates as the collection, execute the fetch request (which, as Mike said above, will still be relatively quick), then delete the objects. See [Aggregate Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB) in the Predicate Programming Guide for more info.